# Service Account key labels?

Tags: gcloud, private-key, service-accounts

I'm setting up service accounts and users/groups under them. If I want to generate a different key for each group/user I attach to the service account, I also want to keep track of this in the situations that someone I assigned a key to gets hacked or decides to break stuff. I want to tie the actions back to the service user, and the key, and then the user.

Is there a way to list key usage? Like a log? Or may label the keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Audit Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) to generate logs for the operations that you want to monitor/control. Also, you can configure who has access to these [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/roles-audit-logging). These settings are in the [auditConfig file](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AuditConfig).

For the keys, If you want further control and management, you can use the [Cloud Key Management Service](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/logging) and also configure Cloud Audit Logging for this service. [Key labeling](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/labeling-keys) can help to order and track this information.